# How do I preserve gdb history for selected commands or disable preserving for selected commands?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I have been debugging a large program on a server. I want to preserve the gdb history because it is not a single day job. I enabled history save and increased the limit but most of my history contains `print variable` commands and many useful commands are overwritten. I wanted to know if there is a way to enable history save for a particular set or even vice versa where I can disable history saving for commands like `step in, next, print`? Any help would be useful

Answer (score 0):

No this is not currently possible in GDB.  The best you can do is `set history size unlimited` which should mean as much history as possible is stored.  I guess there is a limit even for "unlimited" history, this is probably the file size limit for your system.